# код решения функции и ее ООФ

Tags: c, условия

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Регулярно нахожу здесь ответы на свои вопросы(сам чайник), изучаю си в институте и вот первая проблема, на которую я не могу найти ответ, а именно: как правильно определить и вписать в код ООФ? Сам написал громоздкую штуковину, но работает неправильно. Например при вводе значения х=0, у=R, программа выводит -0.000000, но при этом условие на это в коде присутствует(строчка №14). Помогите, пожалуйста, понять, в чем проблема моих условий на ООФ!

```
#include <math.h> 
#include <locale.h>
int main() {
    double A, x, y;
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    printf("Введите значение переменной x: ");
    scanf_s("%lf", &x);
    printf("Введите значение переменной y: ");
    scanf_s("%lf", &y);
    if (y != 0) {
        if (log(fabs((4 * (y * y * y)))) != 0) {
            if (cos(x / y) != 0) {
                A = ((sin(x) * cos(y) - tan(x / y)) / log(fabs(4 * (y * y * y)))) * exp(-x);
                printf("A = %lf", A);
            }
            else {
                printf("Проблема ООФ");
            }
        }
        else {
            printf("Проблема ООФ");
        }
    }
    else {
        printf("Проблема ООФ");
    }
}
```

Comment: `cos(0) != 0`. Что вас удивляет?

Comment: А зачем вообще условие с косинусом? логичнее проверка значения `y`.

Comment: `при вводе значения х=0, у=R` Чему-чему равен `y`?

Comment: ну, это типо у равен любому числу))

Comment: добавил еще картинку(так и не понял, правильно или нет, если нет, то простите!), и на ней как раз функция, которую надо было решить программкой

Comment: Ну, допустим, `y` равен `1.0`. Какое из условий `if` должно нарушиться?

Comment: никакое.. функция решится.. или нет?

Comment: ну так она у вас и решилась... или нет?

Comment: решилось, только у меня вопрос в другом, насчет ООФ

Comment: Если при `х=0, у=1` функция должна решиться и решилась, то почему программа `работает неправильно`? Если функция не должна решиться, то какое условие `if` должно быть нарушено? Если программа работает неверно на каких-то иных входных данных, то на каких?

Comment: А вообще, сравнивать так числа с плавающей запятой - так себе решение. Даже на неравенство нулю проверять так не очень-то хорошая  идея